# How can I report a custom NSWindow title to the accessibility system?

Tags: cocoa, accessibility, nswindow

I've got an Inspector window whose title (sometimes) isn't ideal for reporting to visually impaired users. Is there a way to change the title reported by accessibility without changing the actual window title?

e.g. a window titled "Media" might be better reported to visually impaired users as "Media Browser"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the override value for the window's title. So assuming your window is stored in `myWindow` you want:

```
[myWindow accessibilitySetOverrideValue:@"Media Browser"
                           forAttribute:(NSString *)kAXTitleAttribute];
```